# display contents of external database in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

i know in an application you can display a database in a window by dragging it from the data sources window, but i have a database thats been created programatically, and is not available in the data sources menu. How can i display the database?

Comment: @HighCore Everyone has to start somewhere.  He has found the limitation of that technique, and now he's asking for the next step...

Comment: thanks :) i just wanna learn more, still ABSOLUTELY beginning in this world. If someone looked at my full app, they'd probably laugh at how much unnecessary code and "long-way-rounds" there are :P

Comment: What do you mean by "display database"? You can use `SQL Server Management Studio` for example if I understood you right.

Comment: sorry, more details. I'm using SQL Server Compact edition, and my database and tables are created during the program. I need to show these tables in a form, but obviously i cant connect them through data sources as the databases arent created until the program is started

Comment: I don't know how you are using your DB but I suggest you to use Entity Framework. Here is a good question/answer on how to combine SQL CE and EF - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578222/sql-server-compact-edition-with-entity-framework Also look at what techturtle wrote. I usually use `DataSource` and `DataGridView` to show data in a Win Form.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add an unbound DataGridView on to your form, and then bind your database to it in code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx goes over the manual binding process.  You may be able to just leave out the SQL querying (depending on what your data currently looks like) and bind your existing datasource directly to the DataGridView.

The main pieces you will need to know are this:

**Create a binding source**

```
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
```

**Have your data available in a table, or similar data structure***

```
dataAdapter.Fill(table);
bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
```

**Add the BindingBource as the source of the data in the DataGridView**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

There is potentially a lot more to it, depending on how your data is setup in your application and whether you want the data to be updated, deleted, added to, etc.  This should get you started though.

Comment: As a followup, I found [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb725824) to be helpful as I was getting started on these topics.  It gives a good overview of how connecting controls to database objects works.  It uses VB, not C#, but the principles are the same and the code is pretty close.